# jQuery .empty(); doesn't work on dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I use the jQuery plugin dForm to dynamically popalate this form tag `<form id="myform"></form>` with input fields.

However when I want to empty the the form, with `$("#myform").empty();` it doesn't work. Neither does `$("#myform").children().remove();`

Comment: show the generated html at runtime

Comment: Right you are. The script altered the ID of form. Thanks!

Comment: empty() seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Zt4Rz/2187/